# Can't import anything on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I want to import any library in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import numpy as np
```

But the following error occured:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0aa0b027fcb6> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
138 
139     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 140     from . import _distributor_init
141 
142     from . import core

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
 24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
 25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
 27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
 28     if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

~\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
354 
355         if handle is None:
--> 356             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
357         else:
358             self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 geçerli bir Win32 uygulaması değil
```

If i don't import anything no errors occur. And this situation is the same in all libraries. I have tried to reinstall pip and reinstall numpy. And i have tried also remove notebook and install previous version.

Comment: are you sure you are not mixing python3 and 2? Can you do a !pip freeze and check if the package is there in jupyter?

Comment: Yes those packages are in the list.

jupyter==1.0.0

jupyter-client==5.3.1

jupyter-console==6.0.0

jupyter-core==4.5.0

jupyterlab==1.0.2

jupyterlab-server==1.0.0